# Using ASP.NET MVC3 and with AngularJS

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, angularjs

I've just started developing a completely new site using ASP.NET MVC3 framework and @razor.
I would like to use in the client side the angular JS framework, but the use of both is a bit confusing.
How do I loop an array? 
In ASP.NET MVC I'll write the following HTML:

```
  <ul>
       @foreach (var item in this.Model)
          {                            
                 <li> 
                      @item.Name                                                                
                 </li>
          }
  </ul>
```

In Angular I would write the following HTML:

```
 <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in list">
          {{item.name}}
      </li>
 </ul>
```

Which of the two is the most correct way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is literally no difference between the two as far as the end result is concerned and you can, if you so desire, use either or both.  The difference is in what procedure the code is generated.

In MVC, the final HTML is generated on the server side using data made available on the server side.  You create and populate the data in the model on the server, use the MVC to format the data into a structured html code segment, and then the final html is sent back in the response to the client browser.

In AngularJs, an html template is passed back to the client web browser as well as logic for obtaining the data that will be used in partnership with the template.  Usually the data is retrieved via AJAX from a web service or api of some sort.  Then the JavaScript engine in that browser, using the AngularJs framework, will take that template, retrieve the data and reformat it into a web page on the client end of things.

They literally both provide the same end result.  It's generally just a choice between how and where you want the data formatting to occur.  With most devs I have talked to who are combining MVC and AngularJs, a list is a good example of something that is usually passed off to AngularJs to handle client-side, reserving MVC only for that functionality that AngularJs isn't as well suited for, like security.